# How to get current attributed string in non-editable UITextView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm setting the appearance of a UITextView's text in the storyboard via the attributed string properties. However when I try to access it at runtime in order to copy the attributes object, it returns null.

```
NSAttributedString *atrString = self.contentTextView.attributedText;
NSLog(@"atrString = %@", atrString);
```

Outputs

```
2013-09-20 14:44:19.572 PageTest[69125:70b] atrString = (null)
```

I haven't worked with attributed strings before so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but scouring the documentation has still left me empty handed. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I also have a non-editable UITextView, but I set the attributed text in code, and when I try to access that attributed text after setting it, I get the same output as in your post.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same issue: can't access attributedText on TextView if it is not marked as selectable in Interface Builder (Xcode 6.1). No problem though if the same is done in code. In my case I subclass UITextview:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        self.selectable = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

So I assume something is not quite perfect with IB. Again)

Answer (score 0):

It should works.
May be you forgot to connect IBOutlet contentTextView to the storyboard?

Try to print contentTextView object:

```
NSLog(@"contentTextView = %@", self.contentTextView);
```